# How do you use jsviews with jquery sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsrender, jsviews

I have setup a [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/F9WF6/6/) where I'm using jsViews with JQuery sortable. If you don't change anything, remove works correctly; but if you change the order of the items in the table, then remove any item, it deletes more then one. How do I fix this? I assume there is a way to refresh the observer after the move is done.

```
$("#sortableQuestionArea").sortable({
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
  handle: ".sort-handle",
  update: function(event, ui) {
    // refresh code here??
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is jQueryUI sortable - which does DOM manipulation when you drag and drop. But if you are using JsViews to create a data-driven UI then your UI needs to be data-driven - and to change the order you need to sort the data, not the UI.

UI cannot simultaneously be data-driven and manipulated by moving DOM elements around. Generally, mixing the two is either impossible or very fragile. This applies no matter what data-binding framework you use (JsViews, Knockout, or some other framework...).

Note that in your example, deleting and inserting items is using a data-driven approach - and is not directly adding or removing DOM elements. This is the correct pattern to use for data-driven UI...

Comment: I would still like the user to be able to set the "order" of the items. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: I got it working by adding a drop-down with a order option (1,2,3,...) and it's generated by the index + 1 (so no more sortable).

Comment: OK good. Otherwise you can have buttons to move an item up or down, or write your own drag and drop handlers to determine the target. Then create your modified array: sortedArray, (with items moved up or down) and pass to $.observable(array).refresh(sortedArray). The UI will automatically update. See http://www.jsviews.com/#refresh

Comment: I was able to get sortable to work with refresh... I will post a jsFiddle tomorrow, if you could check it over and let me know if there is anything I could cleanup, that would be great. Thanks again Boris!

Comment: Oh - if it is moving rather than a generic sort, you can do even better - use $.observable(...).move(...) - see http://www.jsviews.com/#move

Comment: Having 2 issues, here is my updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/F9WF6/7/ 1: if you move an item "up" my move code works great, if you move an item "down" (more then 1 position) it will fail. 2: After the sort, if you remove an item from the list, the UI breaks and I get some extra numbers on the page (looks like it's the index printing in the TR). Any ideas?

Comment: I fixed one of the issues by just removing the {^{#index}} and changing it to just {{#index}} http://jsfiddle.net/F9WF6/8/ Now I just need to fix the move "down" bug..

Comment: Okay, it looks like I have the correct index now when moving the items around, however, moving "down" is still not working with .move... even with the correct IDs

Comment: Quick update, so everything seems to be moving now, EXCEPT if you try to move element 0 anywhere.... http://jsfiddle.net/F9WF6/10/

Comment: Ha! the helper I created was causing the issue, I have updated the working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/F9WF6/11/

Comment: Thanks this works a treat. However I made a slight improvement by storing the original index in the sortable start event. This way you don't need to add the data-index attribute to the ui.